# Post JSON from jQuery to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to send a data via jQuery `ajax` function to the PHP script and receive a response - success or failure. The code I am using:

**JavaScript:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'foo.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        foo: 'foo'
    },
    success: function (response) {
        ...
    },
    error: function (response) {
        ...
    }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/json");
echo $_POST['foo']
?>
```

However this always return error, because of `header("Content-Type: text/json");`.

What is done wrong here?

Comment: You could try `application/json` instead.

Comment: @RichGoldMD tried `header("Content-Type: application/json");` - same error.

Comment: So, what is the error text?

Comment: Why is in `data` there's closing `]` instead of `}`?

Comment: add `dataType:'text',` in ajax request and remove the header

Comment: you could also `echo json_encode($_POST['foo']);`

Comment: @RichGoldMD using json_encode only if you are expecting a json response this time he is sending back text only so no need to json_encode

Comment: Perhaps, @guradio, but his Content-type specifies JSON. You can return plain text as json, the encode will add quotes.

Comment: What response do you get if you simply call the url `foo.php` in your browser?

Comment: in your php you will get error missing `;` in echo is that a typo in OP only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would handle the errors correctly server side.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['foo']){
        header('Content-Type: application/json');

        $foo = array(
            "foo" => $_POST['foo'];
        );
        echo json_encode($foo);
    } else {
        header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is the best answer. I can actually also do: `http_response_code(404);`.

Comment: You can indeed choose which error code you return, but 404 would indicate that the client side is using a bad url.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 1):

To get json response include key to make proper json

```
  <?php
    header("Content-Type: text/json");
    $foo = isset($_POST['foo'] ) ?  $_POST['foo'] : "";
    echo json_encode(["foo"=>$foo ]) ;
  ?>
```

As you already define dataType as json in ajax you could remove above header.

Answer (score 1):

if you use `application/json` It should be

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/foo.php',
        method: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ foo: 'foo' }),
        success: function(data) {


        }
    })
```

or `type : 'json'`

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'post'
      url: '/foo.php',
      data: { "foo": "foo" },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {

      }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

As many in the comments have pointed out, the correct MIME type for JSON data is "application/json" – that's not your problem though. The problem is that you're not returning JSON, you're simply echoing out the contents of a variable. If the variable is only a value, it needs at least one key ({"key": "value"}) to be properly converted to a JSON object.

To convert, you echo json_encode($yourvar) after it is an object that represents valid JSON.